# Two 'main' functions in C/C++

Tags: c++, c

Can I write a program in C or in C++ with two main functions?

Comment: What would you expect them to do? Which one should be called?

Comment: To paraphrase Confucius, the journey of a thousand miles begins with a single entry point. You can't have two main()s.

Comment: Dunno if it's relevant, but some programs (e.g. busybox) have a main() implementation that checks the value of argv[0] and then calls through to the relevant something_else_main() function, depending on argv[0]'s value.  That way you can have a single executable act in completely different ways depending on its filename.  Used in conjunction with symbolic links, this can save disk space since no shared code needs to be duplicated in multiple executables.  (a shared library could do the same thing, but it's more of a hassle to maintain)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner, `int main(int argc, char **argv) { int (*start)(int, char **); if (strcmp(argv[0], "file_name1") == 0) start = start_file_name1; else if (strcmp(argv[0], "file_name2") == 0) start = start_file_name2; /* etc */ else start = start_other; return start(argc, argv); }` What's wrong with this that you would want two `main`s? Also, how does having two mains make the executable choose which one to call based on the file name?

Comment: @Shahbaz there's nothing wrong with that code that I can see, although the use of a function-pointer isn't strictly necessary -- i.e. you could have just called start_file_name1(argc,argv) [etc] directly from within the if-then clauses instead, if you wanted to.  As far as having two main()'s, you can't really do that, since you'd get a link error (duplicate function name).  But you can have several functions that are similar to main() but called something else, and main() calls them (like in your example).

Comment: @JohnFeminella That quote actually comes from Laozi.

Answer (score 40):

No. All programs have a single main(), that's how the compiler and linker generate an executable that start somewhere sensible.

You basically have two options:

1. Have the main() interpret some command line arguments to decide what actual main to call. The drawback is that you are going to have an executable with both programs.
2. Create a library out of the shared code and compile each main file against that library. You'll end up with two executables.

Comment: how about this   http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/output-of-a-program-set-2/        int main()
{
    static int i=5;
    if(--i){
        main();
        printf("%d ",i);
    }   
}

Comment: This answer is incorrect. While there may be only one definition of `main` with external linkage, the C standard does not clearly prohibit additional definitions with internal linkage (declared with `static`). Apple LLVM 10.0.0 with clang-1000.11.45.5, at least, accepts this and produces an executable, albeit with a warning.

Answer (score 20):

You can have two functions called `main`. The *name* is not special in any way and it's not reserved. What's special is the *function*, and it happens to have that name. The function is global. So if you write a main function in some other namespace, you will have a second `main` function.

```
namespace kuppusamy {
  int main() { return 0; } 
}

int main() { kuppusamy::main(); }
```

The first `main` function is not special - notice how you have to `return` explicitly.

Comment: Don't you need to return explicitly in the 'real' main() as well?  Right now it's not defined what result code your posted program will return (AFAIK)

Comment: No, the real main() does not require a return value, it defaults to 0.

Comment: Chinmay: To be precise, ::main doesn't require a return *statement*, where it defaults to `return 0;` (`return;` is not valid).  And the return type must remain int regardless.  And using this in any way other than to point out how ::main is special is dubious, YMMV.

Comment: The name really is special and reserved, but it's `::main` instead of `main` (just like `::_a` is reserved but `ns::_a` is not), where I'm not sure the OP really understood that he could make this distinction, much less that he should.

Comment: @Roger, the definition and use of "name" in the Standard is pretty confusing. Actually, clause 3 defines "name" as "the use of an identifier, conversion-function-id, template-id, ... that denotes an entity or label". And it defines equivalence between names like "Two names are the same if they ... are identifiers composed ... are conversion-function-ids having the same type...". It's not defined to include their qualifiers (i.e "qualified name" means "a name preceeded by a qualifier", not a "name that includes ::"). But the Standard uses it inconsistently (like in the template chapters)

Comment: So i'm using "name" as it is defined - not including any qualifiers and stuffs: The name in "::main" is "main", and it's preceeded by a "::". The template chapter and some paragraphs about name lookup uses "name" as "::main" - i.e all parts of names + qualifiers. It's a defect in my opinion, and i spoke to others that feel the same way.

Comment: @Roger, reserved is the name `_a` - if it is declared in the global namespace. There is no name `::_a` if we keep ourself strictly to the definition of "name". See 17.6.3.3.2/1.

Comment: @Roger, and notice that you are allowed to declare `struct main { };` in the global namespace, i think - disproving the statement that `::main` would be a name reserved for the main function :)

Comment: *Technically*, this does not define a second function called `main`: The namespace name gets mangled into the symbol name, and the one, true `main()` is the only symbol that's actually called `main`.

Comment: In addition to additional `main` functions in other name spaces in C++, in C we can define additional `main` functions with internal linkage (declared with `static`).

Comment: why is it not possible in your example to remove the "real" main and write `using kuppusamy::main` instead? I didnt find the exact rule that prevents me from doing this, but didnt dare to ask a question ;)

Answer (score 12):

**Yes**; however, it's [platform specific](http://www.google.com/search?q=linker+weak+symbols) instead of standard C, and if you ask about what you really want to achieve (instead of this attempted solution to that problem), then you'll likely receive answers which are more helpful for you.

Comment: The link to "weak symbols" does not really support your assertion, the final program would still only have one entry point to one main() function.  The concrete main symbol would simply override the weak one.

Comment: "Can I write a program in C or in C++ with two main functions?" Yes, the source code, which is the program in C/C++, will have two main functions.  The compiled version, which is the program in machine code, will still have two main functions.  The linked version, which is actually run on the computer, will only have one.  However, the real point of my answer is that **he's asking the wrong question**, and the answer to it almost certainly *doesn't matter*, and what he should do is ask a different question.

Answer (score 6):

No, a program can have just 1 entry point(which is `main()`). In fact, more generally, you can only have one function of a given name in C.

Answer (score 4):

If one is `static` and resides in a different source file I don't see any problem.

Answer (score 3):

**No**, `main()` defines the entry point to your program and you must only one `main()` function(entry point) in your program.

Frankly speaking your question doesn't make  much sense to me.

Comment: The question is perfectly reasonable I believe. One just wants to know why that is the case.

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by "main function"? If you mean the first function to execute when the program starts, then you can have only one. (You can only have one first!)

If you want to have your application do different things on start up, you can write a main function which reads the command line (for example) and then decides which other function to call.

Answer (score 2):

In some very special architecture, you can. This is the case of the [Cell Processor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cell_%28microprocessor%29#Architecture) where you have a main program for the main processor (64-bit PowerPC Processors Element called PPE) and one or many main program for the 8 different co-processor (32-bit Synergistic Processing Element called SPE).

Comment: Wouldn't that just be nine separate programs rather than one program with nine entry points!?

Comment: What you say is true, but it would be more accurate to represent a SPE as a "physical thread" where the SPE main function would be the entry point of the thread. (this would become MultiProcess Multi-Thread debate ^^)

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot have more than one main() function in C language. In standard C language, the main() function is a special function that is defined as the entry point of the program. There cannot be more than one copy of ANY function you create in C language, or in any other language for that matter - unless you specify different signatures. But in case of main(), i think you got no choice ;)

Answer (score 0):

No,The main() is the entry point to your program,since u can't have two entry points you cant have two main().

Answer (score 0):

You can write it, and it'll compile, but it won't link (unless your linker is non-comformant)

Answer (score 0):

The idiom is to dispatch on the value of `argv[0]`.  With hardlinks (POSIX) you don't even lose diskspace.

Answer (score -3):

Standard C doesn’t allow nested functions but GCC allows them.

```
void main()

{

void main()

{

printf(“stackoverflow”);

}

printf(“hii”);

}
```

The o/p for this code will be -hii

if you use GCC compiler.

There is a simple trick if you want to use 2 main() in your program such that both are successfully executed;you can use define.Example-

```
void main()

{

printf("In 1st main\n");

func1();

}

#define main func1

void main()

{

printf("In 2nd main\n");

}
```

Here the o/p will be:

> In 1st main
>
> In 2nd main
>
> NOTE:here warning conflicting types of func1 will be generated.
>
> And yes don’t change the place of define.