# Compile-time error: Multiple definition of 'main'

Tags: c++

I am getting the following error: Multiple definition of `main'

I have created a new project, there are two c++ files in it:

File 1

```
#include <iostream>

 using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout<<"Hello World";
    //fflush(stdin);
    //getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

File 2

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout<<"Demo Program";
    return 0;
}
```

When I press Build project and Run, I get error. How do I run these files?

Comment: What changes I need to make, do I remove int main() from FILE 2?

Comment: You could change the name and call it where ever you need it. Or have the files in two different projects.

Comment: give both of these functions different names and make main() take arguments (int argc, char* argv[]). Then use the arguments passed to determine which of your two functions to call.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot have two main functions in the same project. Put them in separate projects or rename one of the functions and call it from the other main function.

You can never have more than one main() function in your project since it is the entrypoint, no matter what the parameter list is like.

You can however have multiple declarations of other functions as long as the parameter list is different ([function overloading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading)).

File 1

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout<<"Hello World";
    otherFunction();
    return 0;
}
```

File 2

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void otherFunction()
{
    cout<<"Demo Program";
}
```

Dont forget the appropiate #includes.

Answer (score 4):

You can't have two main functions. In fact you can't have any two functions having the same signature through out your project (not your files).
And as Mr.TAMER said main is a special case, you can't even have two functions called `main`.

Comment: Just continuing AtoMerZ's answer, `main` is a special case, you can't have two functions with the name `main` no matter how their parameter lists (i.e signature) differ.

Answer (score 1):

1. Decide which file you want to be as entry point of your project.
2. In other file, change the method name to some other name. you can call it from the file you chose at step 1.

`main` is entry point of your program and you can't have more than one entry point.

For more clear explanation see this: [Two 'main' functions in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990932/two-main-functions-in-c-c)

Answer (score 0):

You can not use the same function signature in a same project,becouse the compiler start execution from the main(). If you define multiple times of main() then it produce an error.

file1.c

```
#include <iostream>

#include <file2.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
cout<<"Hello World";
//fflush(stdin);
//getchar();
return 0;
}
```

And in file2.h,you can define the function of file2.c(first rename the main() of the file2)