# Makefile for server/client program: "Multiple definitions of main"

Tags: c, makefile, server, client

I am currently writing my first server/client program. Both are to contain a main function and the program is to work as a chat-like system from two terminals. However, when I compile, I get the error "multiple definition of 'main'". Would this be an issue with my makefile? It is as listen below:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-c -Wall
LDFLAGS=-lrt -lm
SOURCES=ser.c cli.c
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.c=.o)
EXECUTABLE=s-talk

all: $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)
    ./$(EXECUTABLE)

.c.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS) 
    $(CC) -pthread $(OBJECTS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@

clean: 
    -rm -f *.o
```

Other simple trial:

```
all: client server

client:
    gcc -pthread -o client cli.c

server:
    gcc -pthread -o server ser.c

clean: 
    -rm -f *.o
```

"Nothing to be done for all"

Comment: You should have *two* targets: One for the server, and one for the client. Now you attempt to link both programs into a single executable file which will not work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compile-time error: Multiple definition of 'main'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8893093/compile-time-error-multiple-definition-of-main)

Comment: Very probably both `ser.c` and `cli.c` have a `main()` function. You need one target for the server executable and another for the client.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I am required to run the program from a single call, though. Is this not possible?

Comment: You can have a target that executes *both* programs, but you can not build it into a single program.

Comment: "*I guess I did something wrong?*" as you do not show what you tried we also can only guess ...

Comment: @alk Apologies, reflected in new edits.

Comment: You forgot the dependencies of the `client` and `server` targets. They need to depend on their respective source file.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Ah, yes. What was I doing? I've got it working now though. Thanks a lot for your help!!

Comment: OT: *And* make it a habit to *always* pass `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` to the compiler as well.

Answer (score -2):

You can create one main thread which will implement `main()` function and create a two separate threads for client and server from main thread. Since you will not have two `main()` functions in your target executable, linker will not say "multiple definition of 'main'" error.

Comment: That is one possibility, but usually client/server applications are different programs that talk to each other via process-messaging mechanisms, like pipes, FIFOs, and sockets. I guess that's what the author is going for, instead of having a multithreaded producer/consumer.

Comment: @giusti is correct. In this case, I'm working with sockets.

Comment: what?  what impedes having two executables with different main on each, and the linker doesn't know about each other and no duplicate main definitions????  What are you trying, to respond or to take _the thread_ far apart from the original problem?